# Control not visible while using Angular.JS with onsenui

Tags: javascript, angularjs, cordova, onsen-ui

I am using Angular.js with onsenui for making mobile application. Here is my Code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="lib/onsen/css/onsenui.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="lib/onsen/css/onsen-css-components.css">

<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.12/angular.min.js"></script>
<script src="lib/onsen/js/onsenui.js"></script>
<script src="js/app.js"></script>
<script>
  ons.bootstrap();
</script>

<body ng-app="myApp">

 <ons-page>
      <ons-toolbar>
        <div class="center">Login</div>
      </ons-toolbar>

      <ons-list>
        <ons-list-item>
          <input type="text" placeholder="Email Address" class="text-input text-input--transparent" style="margin-top:8px; width: 100%;">
        </ons-list-item>

        <ons-list-item>
          <input type="password" placeholder="Password" class="text-input text-input--transparent" style="margin-top:8px; width: 100%;">
        </ons-list-item>
      </ons-list>


      <div class="content-padded">
        <ons-button modifier="large" onclick="">Save</ons-button>
      </div>

      <div class="content-padded">
        <ons-button modifier="large" onclick="">Dont have an account?</ons-button>
      </div>
</ons-page>



<div>
<input type="text" ng-model="name">
<p>Hello {{name}}</p>
</div>
</body>
</html>

 <script>

var myApp = angular.module('myApp',[]);

myApp.controller('HelloCtrl', function($scope){
  $scope.name = "Onsen UI!";
});

</script>
```

everything working fine except this:

```
 var myApp = angular.module('myApp',[]);

    myApp.controller('HelloCtrl', function($scope){
      $scope.name = "Onsen UI!";
```

Controls are not visible on the page. I've checked on Google also.but no help.
Thank you in Advance

Answer (score 1):

Maybe in the HTML you'd need to tell what Controller you want to use? add
ng-controller to the "top" level element that you want to use it with. In your case, it might be that DIV element right above the input element.

```
<div ng-controller="HelloCtrl">
<input type="text" ng-model="name">
<p>Hello {{name}}</p>
</div>
```

In my app, since I only have on controller, so I put it on my BODY element and it works for me.

```
<body ng-app ng-controller="HelloCtrl">

</body>
```

Comment: While your code might (or not) work it would be great if you add a brief explanation about the problem and how does your code solve it. As is it does not provide a full answer according to [help center](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer)

Comment: ah, thanks... I just edited the answer, hopefully it's helpful.